# How to make a part of a div gradient transparent using CSS3 and HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I am developing front end for my client and I am stuck here. I have already tried using (linear gradient) property of CSS but it did not work for me.

Comment: post your code.

Comment: HTML Code
`#grad1 {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255,255,255, 0.5), rgba(255,255,255,1)); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
 }`
CSS Code
`#grad1 {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255,255,255, 0.5), rgba(255,255,255,1)); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
 }
`

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide the code of your tries? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, How much research effort is expected https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: have you tried CSS gradient generator? https://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_gradient-linear_trans

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linear gradient should work.  Just change the percentages below for how far the gradient goes

```css
.background {
  padding: 15px;
  background: url(https://www.fillmurray.com/1000/200) top left no-repeat;
}

.fadeout {
  min-height: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #FFFFFF 29%, transparent 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="fadeout">
  <div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Simple and to the point!

Answer (score 0):

You can use RGBA values un your css, like this:

```css
.container{
  background: silver;
  padding: 30px;
}

 .gradient{
  height: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(red, rgba(0,0,0,0), red);
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="gradient"></div>
</div>
```